# Start multilple activity from broadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I want to start multiple activities from my broadcast receiver. I have two classes i.e ReadContacts and  CallDetails. I want to start them one by one. like first calldetails activity should be started and then next. I have tried below code and it works fine.

```
Intent calldetails = new Intent();
calldetails.setClassName("com.simplereader", "com.simplereader.Calldetails");
calldetails.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(calldetails);
```

then I tried below code to start other activity

```
Intent readcontacts = new Intent(); 
readcontacts.setClassName("com.simplereader", "com.simplereader.ReadContacts");
calldetails.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
context.startActivity(readcontacts);
```

But its not working and application crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are making mistake in this line

```
calldetails.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK)
```

If you want to start readcontacts activity it shoul be

```
readcontacts.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

instead of

```
calldetails.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
```

I think this is the reason.

Answer (score 2):

You must have the `Intent Flag` `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to start an `Activity` from outside of an Activity context so you need to add that flag to your second `Intent`.

I don't know if this is your only problem but if that doesn't fix it then post your logcat so we can see the error.

```
Intent readcontacts = new Intent(); 
readcontacts.setClassName("com.simplereader", "com.simplereader.ReadContacts");
calldetails.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);    // you need this flag
context.startActivity(readcontacts);
```

Answer (score 1):

> FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK   Do not use this flag unless you are implementing your own top-level application launcher.

From the android developer documentation for [intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

You could probably just launch both activities with the new task flag.